# Allow text wrap only at word boundaries in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm having some troubles with Flutters `Text` widget wrapping the text at odd locations if there isn't enough space to display it in a single line:

```
Center(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
       Text("Ready to Grow? Click to join the Tribe!",
       style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       )
    ],
  ),
)
```

In certain situations my text wraps as follows:

```
Ready to Grow? Click to join the Tribe
!
```

This looks quite ugly and I would like Flutter to wrap the line only at white spaces - how can I achieve that? I already tried `softWrap` and the `overflow` property but they don't seem to have any impact on the described behaviour...

Real world screenshot (notice the trailing "!" at the very bottom):

[image: Real world screenshot showing the issue]

Comment: Are you trying to archive singleline-text and shouldn't depend on text length?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh not sure I understand. The goal is to use just one line if the screen width allows it, but on mobile browsers there isn't sufficient space usually and the text has to flow over multiple lines which is fine, but it should break e.g. at spaces between words and treat an exclamation mark (=> any punctuation) as part of the word.

Comment: I think Justify works for you,textAlign:TextAlign.center

Answer (score 1):

I find it quite interesting that you would ask this question, because I've seen a lot of people complaining about the opposite! In general, Flutter is very aggressive about "only wrap words at boundaries", almost too strict, so usually the complain I hear is: "how to make Flutter change line mid-word".

To demonstrate what I mean, look at the following GIF:

[image: demo gif]

From the GIF, we can observe that, Flutter already treats "text!" and "boundaries!" as single words. It tries its best to avoid breaking between the letters and the "!" mark. When needed, it puts the whole word "boundaries!" into its own line.

[image: demo picture]

However, when the screen size is too narrow, it cannot possibly fix the whole word (again, "boundaries!" is treated as a single one word), it will have to break it. Depending on the screen size, line break could happen at any point.

[image: line breaking for word bou-ndaries!]

So overall, Flutter is doing a pretty great job on this regard. You could try to design your UI and draft your copy in a way that avoid using words that are longer than a typical screen width.

Comment: Hm you make a good point, then it must be something more specific about my example which breaks it. I've added a real world screenshot from my device where I have the issue. I will look into what exactly in my code could cause the behavior, but the overall example code I posted pretty much resembles my actual code...

Comment: @schneida Please provide minimal reproducible code example then, because the code you posted in your question (whether before or after your edit) does not produce the behaviour you are describing.